# Android: Alarm triggering

Tags: android, alarm, android-alarms

I am developing an android app where I am setting multiple alarms.Alarm can be set for once,daily and weekly.
I am  setting the alarm hrs,mins and am/pm as

```
     Calendar alarmCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
     alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
     alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
     alarmCalendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 0);

    Long alarmTime = alarmCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

and comparing in miliseconds if time is elapsed as

```
            if(alarmType.equalsIgnoreCase("daily"))
            {
                if (currenttime >= alarmTime)
                {
                    alarmTime+=86400000; // 1day in milliseconds
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, Reciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("keyValue", key);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, key, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi); 
            }

            else if(alarmType.equalsIgnoreCase("weekly"))
            {
                if (currenttime >= alarmTime)
                {
                    alarmTime+=604800000;//1 week in milliseconds
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Alarm.this, Reciever.class);
                intent.putExtra("keyValue", key);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Alarm.this, key, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 604800000 , pi); 

            }
```

Its working fine on some phones and set properly to next day and next week respectively for daily and weekly, when alarmtime is elapsed.But, the problem is,on few phones and tablets,The alarm is not triggered.
Can anybody say whats the problem.Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: Its not triggered at all or there is delay? As it's based on the device time settings/timezone, were the time setting on the device okay?

Comment: Time setting on the device is fine.But for Daily/Weekly its triggering a min before alarm time in some phones  and in some tablets the alarm is not at all triggered.

Comment: Can you add your manifest code? You can send a link to the code